# Middleman build: ruby -v is different from rvm current with .ruby-version

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, middleman

I have a [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com) project in an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and I just want to run `bundle exec middleman build` using a per-project ruby version. So in the root folder of the project I have a `.ruby-version` with this content: `ruby-2.2.0`.

`rvm list` shows

```
rvm rubies

 * ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

Which seems fine. But `ruby -v` shows `ruby 1.9.3p484` and that middleman command fails because it uses the wrong ruby version

```
$ bundle exec middleman build
bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So, how can I make sure that middleman uses the ruby version defined in the project folder ?

Comment: Have you tried `cd .` in the root project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your rvm is using ruby version -1.9.3 . You have to type  `rvm --default use 2.2.0` and after that you can check the active version of ruby by typing `rvm list`

If there is a * sign near the ruby version 2.2.0 then it is using it for default usage . And I hope you will be able to fix this problem.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the `.ruby-version` file if I have to change the default every time ?

Comment: When there is a ruby version is predefined . It means that ..... your  stuff require this version .

Comment: but the `=>` near the ruby version indicates "current" so why should the "default" matter ?

Comment: It matters . You see RVM is stands for Ruby Version manager . And it always install and make a sandbox ready environment for your needs. So now if there is a situation that you will must use ruby 1.9 for development . then you can make default and current ruby usage into some specific version . And it is wise to make a version current and default because there is sometimes issues of permission and granting access.

Comment: Seems to me we are going far from my issue. Let's make it more clear. In my project folder my "current" ruby is 2.2.0 but bundle ignores that. I want to set the ruby version to be run on a per-project basis without having to switch with rvm every time. I thought that was possible with the `.ruby-version` file. Is there a way to achieve this ?